# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC : change DOM element on a timer tick

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I think I have a logic problem in my web application.

I have a class with an event which I pass to my home controller via dependency injection. This event is called every second and the data is sent to the home controller.

How can I display this data on my view? Is there a best practice?

Event call in my class:

```
private void HandleDataChanged(object sender, OpcDataChangeReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    DataChanged(e.Item.Value, ((OpcMonitoredItem)sender).NodeId.ToString());
}
```

Event listener in my HomeController:

```
this.connector.DataChanged += Connector_DataChanged;

private void Connector_DataChanged(object data, string nodeId)
{
    logger.LogInformation(data?.ToString());
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: After the view is rendered, the controller instances ceases to exist, so using this kind of eventing is not a likely candidate. There are two possible models that come to my mind. Either you apply a 'pull' model where you let the web page (through javascript) make callbacks to a Web API controller to check for new information, or you use a 'push' model with a technology such as SignalR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Steven, after the view is rendered, the controller instances ceases to exist.

According to your description, your data is updated and passed to the controller every second, right? You can re-call the controller every second in the View with JavaScript. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function InvokeAction(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async: true,
            data: null,
            url: "/Home/Index",
            success: function(response){
                    //replace elements in your page
                    //$("html").html(response);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log('error')
            }
        })
    }

    $(function () {  
        setInterval(InvokeAction, 1000)
    });  
</script>
```

This way you can get new data from the controller every second, you can try it.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Okay sound logical. Thanks!